# How to get data from 2 tables without joining them?

Tags: .net, sql, linq-to-sql

I need to write on linq2sql analogue of the following query:

```
SELECT A.Field1, B.Field2 FROM tableA A, tableB B
```

How can I do that?

I would start from something like this

```
from a in DBContext.tableA, 
...
select new {Field1=a.Field1, Field2=b.Field2};
```

but what should I write instead of "..."? How to mention 2nd table to be linked?

Thanks.

P.S. Hope I am clear

Comment: You do understand that you did join the tables in the first query? This is called a cross join and it is relatively rare, so be sure this is what you actually need.  If you have two 100 record tables it woudl return a result set of 10,000, so you can see it can be very bad to do this if it isn't what you need.

Comment: Those actually not a tables, but a sub-queries that return 1 row each, each row has 1 field. What I need is to make 1 row with 2 fields instead of 2 rows with 1 field in each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cross join, try

```
from a in DBContext.tableA
from b in DBContext.tableB
select new {Field1=a.Field1, Field2=b.Field2};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you select data from two tables without joining them, you will get a *cross join*, which is every row in the first table joined with every row in the second table. This is probably not what you want.